# Quartz.NET One-Shot Job

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I have created an ASP.NET MVC UI to create fire and forget jobs for the Quartz.NET scheduler running as a window service (RAMJobStore) but I am just wondering whether I need to clean up the executed jobs. Can anyone shed some lights? The following code is what I used to create the Job from MVC controller.

```
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();

JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
map.Put("...", "......");

IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<OneTimeJob>()
    .WithIdentity("onetimejob_" + Guid.NewGuid(), "default")
    .UsingJobData(map)
    .Build();
ISimpleTrigger simpleTrg = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("onetimetrigger_" + Guid.NewGuid(), "default")
    .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1))
    .Build();

// schedule the job
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrg);
```

Comment: You could make things even simpler by making your job durable in scheduler (just add it once). And trigger it with different job data maps (via trigger map) using scheduler.TriggerJob(JobKey jobKey, JobDataMap data). You can access the data from MergedJobDataMap that contains both job specific and trigger specific data.

Answer (score 3):

When the job is triggered and executed, the job will be deleted by Quartz. Though, given that you are using a new GUID it seems unlikely to be a problem whether the job is deleted or not. It is highly unlikely that a name clash would occur.